# JS / React Carousel with useEffect & Hooks - Horizontal scrolling to <a> tags in carousel?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have built the following Carousel / Image Slider that treats the children provided to it as Slides. So far I am not using much JS, it's all pretty much HTML & CSS (apart from the styled-components and the fact the whole thing is a function)

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

let Wrapper = styled.div`
  width: 100%;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow-x: auto;

  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;

  & > div {
    scroll-snap-align: start;
  }
`;

let Slide = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  padding: 30px;
`;

let SlideLink = styled.a`
  padding-right: 3px;
  color: purple;
  color: ${props => (props.isActive ? 'purple' : `gray`)};
`;

const Slider = ({ children }) => {
  const [activeSlide, setActiveSlide] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    // ??
  }, [activeSlide]);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setActiveSlide(activeSlide - 1)}>PREV</button>
      {children.map((child, i) => {
        return (
          <SlideLink
            href={`#slide-${i + 1}`}
            isActive={activeSlide === i}
            onClick={e => {
              setActiveSlide(i);
            }}
          >
            {i + 1}
          </SlideLink>
        );
      })}

      <Wrapper>
        {children.map((child, i) => {
          return <Slide id={`slide-${i + 1}`}>{child}</Slide>;
        })}
      </Wrapper>

      <button onClick={() => setActiveSlide(activeSlide + 1)}>NEXT</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default Slider;
```

Its working quite well, but I'd also like to use the `NEXT SLIDE` and `PREVIOUS SLIDE` buttons for navigation. But I'm not sure how to do this with this setup. I would need to scroll horizontally inside the Wrapper I guess? Or could I just programmatically "jump" to certain ids, like when clicking on the `<a href="#slide-1" />`-tags somehow?

I'd really appreciate some advice, I'm quite stuck and feel I might have coded it in a not so optimal way?

Comment: One possible approach would be to line slides up and transition between them whenever `prev/next` button is clicked. For starters, you can simply rely on item index to identify which slide should be in the view.

Comment: use a library man :D

Comment: Do you specifically want it to scroll sideways? An alternate approach that may be easier is to use `overflow-x: hidden` instead of `auto` and then add an intermediate wrapper between the slideshow wrapper and the slides. Transition the intermediate wrapper with `translateX` by `activeSlide * 100%`. That also lets you variable numbers of columns (e.g., 3 slides side-by-side on desktop, one slide on mobile) just with CSS, without having to modify the JS. You'd have to add swipe support in JS, though.